# c++ code with standard containers and constants references exhibits unexpected memory

Tags: c++, stl, containers

We have the code below (roughly the same) in production, and am seeing some weird behaviour. The section marked 'HERE' always outputs whatever was last inserted into the accrualRows dictionary. If we change the hash_map to store pointers to 'Row', then everything works fine. I'm a bit suspicious of using a const & in the std containers.. you can't use references in standard containers, but these are constant references, which I know in some places are treated different (eg: you can assign temporary variables and literals to constant references)

```
#define hash_map std::tr1::unordered_map
//build up a hash map between deal index and the row for ones we care about

    typedef hash_map<int, const Row &> RowMap;
    RowMap accrualRows;    
    for( int i = 0; i < listItems.numResults(); ++i )
    {
        const Row & accrual = listItems.getResult(i);
        if( accrual.someVar )
        {
            accrualRows.insert( std::make_pair( accrual.index, accrual ) );
         }
    }

    //go through every row and if deal index is in our accrualRows, then
    //modify 

    for( int i = 0; i < numResults(); ++i )
    {
        ExposureRow & exposure = getResult(i);
        RowMap::const_iterator it = accrualRows.find( exposure.index );

        if( it != accrualRows.end() )
        {
            // HERE
            cout << it->second.someVar << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store references in a container.  A container can only store *objects*.  If you need to store a "reference," you can either use `std::reference_wrapper` or use a pointer.

Comment: I thought that could be a problem, but I expected gcc to raise an error (it does if you try to use non constant pointers). Is it because the value_type must be assignable? (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Assignable.html)

Comment: Yes, the `value_type` must be assignable.  Both `reference_wrapper` and a pointer are assignable.  You cannot use _references_ because they are not _objects_.